Loading .NET profiler for a specific process
I have my own.NET profiler built from the CORPROFILER API and am trying to monitor various.NET processes.
For example,
 
I have 2 processes:

A.exe 
B.exe

 
I have added my COR_PROFILER ENABLE entry to everything in my system environmental variable.Currently When the A.exe and B.exe start, I can get the profiler loaded successfully from the event viewer. My.NET profiler is attached for both .NET processes.
 
But I need to monitor only process A alone (A.exe) and not process B.
How do I restrict .NET profiler loading from a specific process?
I tried to get the process name in the profiler initialize method and return E_FAIL for process B. But it always writes a .NET runtime error message when process B starts which is not good. 
How do I avoid the .NET runtime error message from the .NET profiler?
Which HRESULT error code did not write any logs?
 

In you initialize get the process name.  When that process name is the one you want to silence then just return either
CORPROF_E_PROFILER_CANCEL_ACTIVATION for C++
or
unchecked((int)0x80131022) for C#
That should silently cancel the activation for the process.

Thank you @cogitoboy. When we return CORPROF_E_PROFILER_CANCEL_ACTIVATION from c++ code. Getting the below message from the event viewer as information, "NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - The profiler has requested that the CLR instance not load the profiler into this process.  Profiler CLSID: '{SAMPLE_DOTNET_PROFILER}'.  Process ID (decimal): 2772.  Message ID: [0x2516]" and Application stopped immediately.

Event viewer message is ok. But application should run without any issue.
